# findViewById inside a Static Method

Tags: android, static-methods, findviewbyid

I have this static method:

```
public static void displayLevelUp(int level, Context context) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_level_coast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));  // this row

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
    text.setText("This is a custom toast");

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(level), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the first`findViewById` to play nice with this as it says it is a non-static method. I understand why it says that, but there must be a workaround?  I passed `context` into this method but couldn't work them out together.

Comment: You don't need to pass a context object, but a view object. The one that is holding your views

Comment: Why not just make the view a class wide variable and access it that way

Comment: @Wamasa That is right answer..post it

Comment: @tyczj  I actually used your suggestion and it works great!  You can post that as answer.

Comment: why does it have to be static anyway ?

Comment: @njzk2 its being called from another Static Method that is required to be static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing you can do is make the view a class wide variable and use that. I dont actually recommend doing that but it will work if you need something quick and dirty.

Passing in the view as a parameter would be the preferred way

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with a static method use Activity instead of Context as parameter and do a activity.findViewById like so:

```
public static void displayLevelUp(int level, Activity activity) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toastText, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar_container));  // this row
```

Another way to do it is to pass the parent ViewGroup as parameter instead of a Context or Activity:

```
public static void displayLevelUp(int level, ViewGroup rootLayout) {
    View layout = rootLayout.inflate(rootLayout.getContext(), R.layout.custom_level_coast, rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));  // this row
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a little weird. But you can pass the root view as parameter.

```
//some method...
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root);
displayLevelUp(level, context, root);
//some method end...


public void displayLevelUp(int level, Context context, ViewGroup root) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_level_coast,
        root);

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();

Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(level), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();

}
```