# How to implement a delayed button press using AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, static-methods, findviewbyid

I'm trying to set an alarm that presses a button after a specified delay.

I've followed a tutorial:

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html#comment-form

This only works if I declare the class that extends BroadcastReceiver as static, in which case, I cannot use "findViewById" to access the button.

A similar question was asked in:

[findViewById inside a Static Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342004/findviewbyid-inside-a-static-method)

where the solution was to define the main view as a class wide variable. If this is the only solution, how do I do that exactly?

Thanks in advance! Have been really struggling with this one.

Comment: Why are you trying to press a button after a delay, rather than doing the **actual work** that is otherwise triggered by the button press?

Comment: It's a toggle button, so apart form executing it's functionality, I need to change it's state. Even if I didn't, I have a similar problem accessing the appropriate classes from inside a static method.

Answer (score 1):

`AlarmManager` is for cases where you have a long enough delay where the user is likely no longer in your app. If you have a short delay (e.g., a few seconds), don't use `AlarmManager`, but instead use `postDelayed()`, called on some `View` (e.g., the `ToggleButton` you are interested in), to get a `Runnable` to run when you want.

In the cases where `AlarmManager` is appropriate, you need to understand that **you may not have a UI**. Your process may have been terminated between when the user was last in your UI and when the `AlarmManager` event occurs. Hence, you may not have your `ToggleButton` or any other Java objects associated with your UI.

Hence, when the `AlarmManager` event occurs, your `IntentService` (triggered directly, or perhaps indirectly via `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` if you are using a `_WAKEUP` alarm) needs to be able to do the actual business logic itself and not be dependent upon objects that may no longer exist. In addition, the `IntentService` could use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.) to raise an event, saying "hey, UI layer, could you update yourself, if you exist?". Your activity/fragment can be registered for that event when it is in the foreground and can update the UI in those cases. That way, the work gets done, and the `ToggleButton` can be affected, without the `AlarmManager` code actually trying to change the `ToggleButton`.

Comment: What the button actually dose is send a specific TCP command over a socket which is also implemented in the app. The delay should be limited to a couple of hours. I think I can't use postDelayed() since the device might fall asleep in the duration. How would I be able to do that using the EventBus?

Comment: @sas: "What the button actually dose is send a specific TCP command over a socket which is also implemented in the app" -- then your `IntentService` will need to be able to set up the socket and send the command. "I think I can't use postDelayed() since the device might fall asleep in the duration" -- after two hours, your process will ideally have been terminated to free up memory for other apps. "How would I be able to do that using the EventBus?" -- what is "that"? Here is an example of updating a UI: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot